# OracleBulkCopy: different behavior between Oracle 12c and 19c

Tags: oracle12c, odp.net, oracle19c

Crossposting here from the official Oracle forum:
I'm transferring data from an SQLite database to an Oracle Database with fully managed ODP.NET, 4.122.19.1. So far it has been ***12c*** which worked flawlessly, but when writing to Oracle ***19c*** I get the error "**ORA-39822**: A new direct path operation is not allowed in the current transaction."
The program flow is basically like this (details omitted for brevity):

```cs
using (var transaction = oracleConnection.BeginTransaction())
{
    foreach (var dataTable in dataTables)  // dataTables is a collection of - well, DataTables
    {
         using (var bulkCopy = new OracleBulkCopy(oracleConnection))
         {
             bulkCopy.WriteToServer(dataTable);
         }
    }
    transaction.Commit();
}
```

When trying to write the second DataTable I get the aforementioned error which is pretty self explaining: I guess I'm supposed to start a new transaction for each DataTable. As I want the whole transfer to be an all-or-nothing operation I hesitate to change the code accordingly.
So - is there any setting in Oracle 19c that re-enables the behavior that I see in Oracle 12c?

Answer (score 0):

Alex Keh from Oracle confirmed that each `WriteToServer()` call must be inside its own `Transaction` so that the program flow has to be:

```cs
    foreach (var dataTable in dataTables)
    {
         using (var bulkCopy = new OracleBulkCopy(connection))
         {
             using (var transaction = connection.BeginTransaction())
             {
                   bulkCopy.WriteToServer(dataTable);
                   transaction.Commit();
             }
         }
    }
```

Discussion [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20230127070346/https://community.oracle.com/tech/developers/discussion/4512569/ora-39822-under-19c-but-not-under-12c#Comment_16860789)